# What happens if the computer I am accessing remotely via TeamViewer is infected with malware, etc?

Tags: security, vpn

Is  there a risk it can infect say my computer even if I don't download a file?

Comment: It's probably different with Microsoft Remote Desktop if you forward your disks to the remote controlled machine.

Comment: @DanielBeck: An often overlooked vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about it , you will not get infected, if it was VPN site to site then you could get infected, but not using TeamViewer.

Comment: Thanks. I presume if I downloaded a file via Teamviewer, I could potentially get infected assuming the file was laden with viruses, etc. Also what do you mean by `VPN site to site`?

Comment: yes, if you download an infected file via Teamviewer then you can get infected. VPN site to site is basically like you are on the same network as the computer you want to remote to it.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Technically, you'd have to run the infected file first. But you get the idea.